# Squid reverse proxy: maintenance mode

Tags: proxy, squid, maintenance

Currently I am trying to configure my squid (3.1) reverse proxy to always display a static webpage when the one and only backend webserver is under maintenance.
There is no need for an automatic switchover. The maintenance mode shall be activated by a manual config change.

The squid docs and wiki were not really helpful on this point.
My idea was to block every request and display a static webpage as a `deny_info` with a 200 status code like so:

```
acl everyone src 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
## Testing with my client ip address:
# acl everyone src 10.123.0.40/32
http_access deny everyone
deny_info 200:/etc/squid/maintenance.html everyone
```

I placed that snippet **before** any other `http_access` rule and tried that configuration by only blocking my own clients traffic but there was no effect using `squid -k reconfigure`. It may work when I use `sudo service squid restart` but I do not want to test it right now because at the time there a many users using that service and a squid restart takes about half a minute (for every test).

My questions:

1. Is that configuration correct for that purpose?
2. Do I need to use `sudo service squid restart` for the changes to take effect or is there simply something wrong?
3. Is there a better solution to display a static maintenance page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- squid 3.1.x is like thousand years old.
- squid 3.x completely lost the ability to *soft reconfiguring*, thus it requires restart to apply config changes. This means you will lose your client connections to the site. Each time it will be like a flash-DoS.

To conclude: this renders squid unsuitable for using as a reverse-proxy for a website in a production environment. Consider using `nginx`.

If despite these warnings you are still planning to stick with squid, then you should write an [redirector](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Redirectors) which will be checking if a decoy page should be in effect, to neutralize the restart problem. This redirector may be written using any script language you know: perl, python, ruby or even `/bin/sh`. The logic is simple: the redirector will check some sign (for example a file flag) if the decoy page should be shown, if not - it will simply pass the request to a backend. It may even check the viability of such backends.

But `nginx` has this functionality out-of-the-box.

Comment: Agreed squid is bad choice for a reverse proxy... Nginx  or haproxy are far better tools for this function